# Memory allocated but not deallocated when called finish() in android

Tags: android, performance, memory

I have an app and I am facing performance issues. App crahes a lot. I tried to monitor the memory allocation part in my android studio and I found out the reason why my app was crashing so much. My app starts at 19MB. I go through different activities and then I press back button inside my app in which I'm calling `finish()`. What I realized was that memory was allocated to my apps but even after calling finish no memory was deallocated. I am obviously doing some big blunders but can someone list some reasons to why this might be happening. I'll really appreciate it. Oh yeah my app went to 72 MBs. The memory was never deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check memory leakage? Android would have killed the `process` but memory allocated by `components` may not be freed by GC. It may happen due to holding reference of the components or their members`.

As a note: Android always kills the process **not** components. And its our job to insure that they are getting garbage collected (yes, GC does it on its own, but if we are holding reference to any components, it won't get garbage collected).

Edit 1: you can investigate the same as detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html). Or you can use this awesome [library by square](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

Edit 2: for example, your holding reference of a `view` in `async task`, so that you will be able to update it when `task` finishes. But while `task` is still running, `activity` gets destroyed due to screen rotation. Here, `android` will kill that `foreground process` but GC won't be able to collect allocated memory because `async task` is holding `view`'s reference and thus activity also won't get collected because `view` is tied up to its `activity`. And then all members of that activity will also not get collected.

Comment: yeah obviously that's the only explanation but how do i check leakage?

Comment: doesn't GC get called on it's own??
You mean i have to call GC myself?

Comment: Yes, GC gets called on its own. But if you are holding reference to any components, it won't collect it. That's the reason of memory leak.

Comment: thanks, i'll check it out and if it helps me in solving the problem i'll accept the answer :)

Comment: One more question . Can you give me a tiny example how a component might be getting memory allocated but not freed ? I am kinda bad at understanding memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried to see if I made any mistake but sadly couldn't find it but i tried this after calling finish and it deallocated a lot of space.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

But i thought that gc is called automatically so if i am wrong can someone tell me if there are any dangers of calling gc on your own and if there aren't well then this line worked for me :)